How can I resolve this error in Pyinstaller?
My computer is Windows 11, and when I run the command pyinstaller --onefile file.py after installing the library with pip3 install pyinstaller, I get the following error:
"pyinstaller is not recognized as an internal or external command, program or executable batch file.
I have tried with administrator permissions but it gives the same result.
Image

The message is telling you that either pyinstaller does not exist on your system, or your PATH environment variable does not include the path to where it is installed.

if you installed without error then it didn't create script which runs python with PyInstaller - but you can try to run python -m PyInstaller ... (it has to be upper P and I). Other idea: it put script pyinstaller in some folder (which you don't have on environment variable PATH) and you have to find it and use /full/path/to/pyinstaller ...

First make sure that where you have installed the pyinstaller, in env or in global python. Then try to run the build command there.
If it still gives an error then try to use python -m PyInstaller --onefile file.py instead of pyinstaller --onefile file.py. Keep the case in above commands as it is.
This should solve your issue. But if still doesn't then try to uninstall the package from global and venv (remake venv if possible), this should remove any incorrect settings, so you can reinstall and use it again.
Also one of the common reasons this might be occurring because you only have your global python path (and its scripts folder path) in your PCs environment variables. So in that case using python -m PyInstaller ... command would be your solution as I don't recommend adding your venv path and scripts folder to your PCs environment variables.
